# Parsing multiple values with Google Refine

Tags: openrefine, grel

I've a CSV column with content like this (just an example):

```
[{"qual"=>"05-Admmin "name"=>"CLARK C COHO"}, {"qual"=>"20-Soc Con", "name"=>"ALPHA S A"}, {"qual"=>"20-Soc Con", "name"=>"JACK SA"}
```

I would like to extract automatically the values from "name" field and separate it by comma, resulting in something like this: CLARCK C COHO, ALPHA S A, JACK SA and so on.

I know that I can get a specific value with this code:

```
value.parseJson()[0].name
```

I've been reading the documentation but i'm not figuring out how to loop this between all fields.

Any tips?

EDIT:
Here is another example of the column. The content really look like this:

```
[{"qual"=>"49-SocAdm", "name"=>"ALVARO R L"}, {"qual"=>"49-SocAdm", "name"=>"GABRIEL G L"}]
```

Comment: You must use a `forEach()` to loop the Json, then a join to get a comma separated string: `forEach(value.parseJson(), e, e.name).join(',')` I can't try on your example, is not a valid Json.

Comment: @EttoreRizza I think worth posting this as an answer rather than comment so it can be accepted

Comment: @Owen : I'm not absolutely sure that's the right answer. The json posted as an example is weird. I'm not even sure it's a Json.

Comment: @EttoreRizza Fair enough :) Agree - that's not JSON, but your comment is correct in terms of 'how to loop between all fields'. The equivalent JSON to the data posted above would be:
```[
  {
    "qual": "05-Admmin",
    "name": "CLARK C COHO"
  },
  {
    "qual": "20-Soc Con",
    "name": "ALPHA S A"
  },
  {
    "qual": "20-Soc Con",
    "name": "JACK SA"
  }
]```. @abitporu can you edit question to contain valid JSON?

Comment: If the actual content of the @abitporu's csv really looks like this, they are rather regular expressions that will have to be used.

Comment: Hi @EttoreRizza, unfortunately, the content looks exactly like that.
I've inserted another example. So should I try regex? Do you have any tip on that? Or maybe I could try to fix the column (find/replace this "=>" for ":"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in your CSV is not in JSON format. I do not know what it is. A kind of key-value format, but I do not know which one. In addition, it sometimes lacks a comma or a bracket. We could try to transform it into a valid JSOn, but it will be easier to extract information using regular expressions. Here is an example with Python / Jython.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'"name"=>"(.+?)"', re.M)

return ", ".join(pattern.findall(value))
```

[image: screenshot]